# y.tab.h and y.tab.c files are not generated by bison on Win32

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I run the following command on Windows Server 2012 with latest Bison and Flex.

```
bison --yacc -dv test.y
```

But only a y.output file is generated.

I need `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`. Why are they not generated?

The error message that I didn't notice before:

```
m4: cannot open `Files': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `(x86)\GnuWin32\Bison/share/bison': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `D:\Program': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `Files': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `(x86)\GnuWin32\Bison/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just put the filename in quotes.

Comment: @EJP Which file name to put in quotes? It is the path of bison.exe that cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works now. Bison cannot handle space in path string. Never expected such an issue. Thanks EJP for the reminding.